# Mixin (PXTOEM) provides error in CSS output

Tags: sass, drupal-7, mixins

I use Drupal [FortyTwo theme.](https://www.drupal.org/project/fortytwo) The theme provides a mixin named PXTOEM:

```
//  PXTOEM
//  Calculate percentage with font-size as context
@function pxtoem($pixels...) {
  $result: '';

  @each $item in $pixels {
    $result: $result + ($item + 0) / $default-font-size + em + ' ';
  }

  @return #{$result};
}
```

In my `scss file` I use it like:

```
.header-menus {
  padding: pxtoem(0, $grid-gutter-width);
}
```

But after compiling it doesn't get the proper output?

```
padding: 0/pxem 0.75/pxem; (see screenshot)[![Screenshot][2]][2]
```

Comment: What are the values of `$default-font-size` and `$grid-gutter-width`?

Comment: In `_settings.scss` I have `$default-grid-gutter-width: 30;` and on top of the scss file where I have `.header-menus {}` I have `$grid-gutter-width: $default-grid-gutter-width;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `+ 0` you should add pixels: `+ 0px`. And instead of `+ em` use `+ 0em`.
Sassmeister [demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/7abec8ad3d986f948443a6804855a0c6).
If you can not modify source code of the theme, create your own function.

```
$default-font-size: 16px;

//  PXTOEM
//  Calculate percentage with font-size as context
@function pxtoem($pixels...) {
  $result: '';

  @each $item in $pixels {
    $result: $result + ((($item + 0px) / $default-font-size) + 0em) + ' ';
  }

  @return #{$result};
}

.header-menus {
  padding: pxtoem(0, 30, 30px);
}
```

Css output:

```
.header-menus {
  padding: 0em 1.875em 1.875em ;
}
```